# ASP.NET Core app targeting full framework — InProcess IIS?

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core app targeting full framework 4.6. when I deploy to IIS the application runs out of process. That was the default as ASP.NET Core 2.0 and 2.1, then is said that in ASP.NET Core 2.2 is possible to run InProcess, but Does this apply to  ASP.NET Core apps targeting full framework?
In Server with IIS, I have installed the latest version of .NET Core 2.2 Runtime & Hosting Bundle for Windows (v2.2.3)

[image: How project was created]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows#in-process-hosting-model) state that this is not supported when targeting the .NET Framework:

> The in-process hosting model isn't supported for ASP.NET Core apps that target the .NET Framework.